# how to test Facebook Login for my mobile app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am adding Facebook login to my app so to get permission to post photos for users. Having created the code, I now want to test that it works. So naturally I am using my own Facebook again to see that the system works. The first time I went through, I found some stuff I didn't like. So I made the changes. Now that I want to test again using my Facebook again, when I login, Facebook keeps telling me that I already gave the app permission. I tried uninstalling the app and then re-install, just in case it was caching locally. But that didn't help. So my question is: how do I get to reuse my account to login and request the permissions again? I hope the question is clear. If not, please ask for clarification.

I am experiencing this problem with android. But I am guessing it's similar for iOS, so I use both tags.

Comment: I didn't work with Facebook , but I presume, there is some kind of App ID, and permissions for that App ID are kept on a Facebook server. So, you should be able to cancel permissions for an app somewhere on your Facebook page.

Comment: @FreeNickname I am assuming you mean for each user who signs up, I can find them and remove them. I have been looking for that, but I can't find it. I can see the number of users on my app (which is one since I am the only one so far). But I don't see a way to revoke that user.

Comment: Not exactly. I meant that each user can revoke access for your app. So, if you are a user yourself, you should be able to revoke access for it somewhere. I think, luschn found exactly that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the following page in your browser: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

Your App should be in that list, just remove it to test the authorization again.